# SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play() not working after being published

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, audio, windows-7

```
  SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
```

This is working fine in my application when i am testing it on my local srver without publishing it , but when it is published the sound is not produced ,means the code does not play the sound.

Any Views????

Comment: Your tags include ASP.NET - are you actually trying to play the sound on the *client* computer? If so, I expect you'll need Javascript - the `System.Media` namespace is unlikely to help you.

Comment: So How do i play a sound on client computer like facebook does when it has a new notification for the user?

Comment: As I said before, I suspect you'll need to use Javascript - or Flash, or something similar that's executing *on the client*.

Comment: Unless, of course, you want the server to beep on every request ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work after being published, and keep your notification sound in your Solution

```
HtmlGenericControl sound = new HtmlGenericControl("<embed src=\"" + path + "\" autostart=\"true\" hidden=\"true\"></embed>");

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(sound);
```